# Как сделать перевод на другой Таб(вкладку) после воспроизведения видео

Tags: javascript, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Приветствую всех ребята помогите.. есть 2 таба в одном табе видео во втором галерея. Как автоматический переход на таб с галереей после окончания видео. что написать в функции. Вот код :в инпуте радио два таба один видео-таб, другой галерея. первым открывается видео таб и автоматически воспроизводится , в другом табе галерея при клике на галерею срабатывает пауза на видео и плавно переключается на таб галереи

```
    <a href="#modalOpen" title="">
    <label onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').play()">
        <img src="full/banner.png" class="button1" onclick="showModal();">
    </label>>
</a>
        <div id="modalOpen" class="Window">
    <div id="centerlayer">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="thumbs/header.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="notebook2">
            <input type="radio" name="notebook2a" id="notebook2a_1" checked="checked">
            <input type="radio" name="notebook2a" id="notebook2a_2">
                <label name="button2" class="button2" onclick="closeModal()">
                    <img src="full/iconX.png" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').pause()">
                </label>
            <div id="video" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').play()">
                <label for="notebook2a_1" style="margin-top:7px;">Video</label>
                <video class="videocontent" id="videoplay" src="full/ps.mp4" poster="full/poster.png" controls autoplay onended="smoothly()" ></video>
            </div>
        <div id="slides" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').pause()">
            <label for="notebook2a_2" style="margin-top:6px;">Gallery</label>
                <div class="container">
                    <ul id="slides">
                        <li class="slide showing"><img src="full/1.png"></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img src="full/2.png"></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img src="full/3.png"></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img src="full/4.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="controls" id="previous">
                        <img src="full/left_arrow.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls" id="next" style="left:50px;float:right">
                        <img src="full/right_arrow.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <ul class="thumbs">
                        <li class="img1"><img src="Thumbs/1.png" class="mini active" data-full-url="full/1.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/1_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/1.png'"/></li>
                        <li class="img2"><img src="Thumbs/2.png" class="mini"  data-full-url="full/2.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/2_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/2.png'"/></li>
                        <li class="img3"><img src="Thumbs/3.png" class="mini"  data-full-url="full/3.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/3_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/3.png'"/></li>
                        <li class="img4"><img src="Thumbs/4.png" class="mini" data-full-url="full/4.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/4_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/4.png'"/></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
<script>
    function closeModal(){
        var modal = document.getElementById('modalOpen');
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
    function showModal() {
        var modal = document.getElementById('modalOpen');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
    for(var i=0; i<controls.length; i++){
        controls[i].style.display = 'inlinex`-block';
    }

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
    var currentSlide = 0;

    function nextSlide(){
        goToSlide(currentSlide+1);
    }

    function previousSlide(){
        goToSlide(currentSlide-1);
    }

    function goToSlide(n){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
    }


    var next = document.getElementById('next');
    var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

    next.onclick = function(){
        nextSlide();
    };
    previous.onclick = function(){
        previousSlide();
    };

    document.getElementById('videoplay').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
    function myHandler(e) {
        document.getElementById('video').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('slides').style.display = 'block';
    }
    function smoothly() {
        nextSlide();
    }
```

Comment: Проверте последние строки вашего `css`

Comment: но все ровно у меня этот код нечего нормального не отображает что бы проверить и понять, у вас там есть например класс `active` для табов? как один отображается у вас а другой скрыт?

Comment: Все это добавте в вопрос и обясните как эти `radio` связаны с табами

Comment: У тебя вообще там ՝next՝ и `prev` работают?

Comment: Next и prev работают - они двигают изображения в галерее. Они связаны только с галереей и меняют картинки

Comment: Посмотрите я добавил картинку может так будет понятней , нужно чтобы после этого видео автоматически перенеслось на таб с галереей

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan Посмотрели?

Comment: Да то что ты хочешь сделано с помошю `css` а не `javascript`

Comment: Так еще ничего не сделано , этот сайт сделан так и с javascript функциями так и css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `javascript` есть событие для завершения проигрывания
вот этот кусок кода вам надо написать что бы перехватить это событие, а потом сделайте то что нужно

```
document.getElementById('videoplay').addEventListener('ended',myHandler,false);
function myHandler(e) {
    document.getElementById('video').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('slides').style.display = 'block';
}
```

Вот рабочий код который вы хотели, посмотрите внимательно что я поправил в коде:

```html
 <body>
<a href="#modalOpen" title="">
    <label onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').play()">
        <img src="full/banner.png" class="button1" onclick="showModal();">
    </label>>
</a>
        <div id="modalOpen" class="Window">
    <div id="centerlayer">
        <div class="header">
            <img src="thumbs/header.png"/>
        </div>
        <div class="notebook2">
            <input type="radio" name="notebook2a" id="notebook2a_1" checked="checked">
            <input type="radio" name="notebook2a" id="notebook2a_2">
                <label name="button2" class="button2" onclick="closeModal()">
                    <img src="full/iconX.png" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').pause()">
                </label>
            <div id="video" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').play()">
                <label for="notebook2a_1" style="margin-top:7px;">Video</label>
                <video class="videocontent" id="videoplay" src="full/ps.mp4" poster="full/poster.png" controls autoplay></video>
            </div>
        <div id="slides" onclick="document.getElementById('videoplay').pause()">
            <label for="notebook2a_2" style="margin-top:6px;">Gallery</label>
                <div class="container">
                    <ul id="slides">
                        <li class="slide showing"><img src="full/1.png"></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img src="full/2.png"></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img src="full/3.png"></li>
                        <li class="slide"><img src="full/4.png"></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="controls" id="previous">
                        <img src="full/left_arrow.png"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls" id="next" style="left:50px;float:right">
                        <img src="full/right_arrow.png"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    <ul class="thumbs">
                        <li class="img1"><img src="Thumbs/1.png" class="mini active" data-full-url="full/1.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/1_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/1.png'"/></li>
                        <li class="img2"><img src="Thumbs/2.png" class="mini"  data-full-url="full/2.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/2_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/2.png'"/></li>
                        <li class="img3"><img src="Thumbs/3.png" class="mini"  data-full-url="full/3.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/3_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/3.png'"/></li>
                        <li class="img4"><img src="Thumbs/4.png" class="mini" data-full-url="full/4.png"
                                              onmouseover="this.src='thumbs/4_over.png'"
                                              onmouseout="this.src='thumbs/4.png'"/></li>
                    </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        </div>
<script>
    function closeModal(){
        var modal = document.getElementById('modalOpen');
        modal.style.display = 'none';
    }
    function showModal() {
        var modal = document.getElementById('modalOpen');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
    }
    var controls = document.querySelectorAll('.controls');
    for(var i=0; i<controls.length; i++){
        controls[i].style.display = 'inlinex`-block';
    }

    var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides .slide');
    var currentSlide = 0;

    function nextSlide(){
        goToSlide(currentSlide+1);
    }

    function previousSlide(){
        goToSlide(currentSlide-1);
    }

    function goToSlide(n){
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide';
        currentSlide = (n+slides.length)%slides.length;
        slides[currentSlide].className = 'slide showing';
    }


    var next = document.getElementById('next');
    var previous = document.getElementById('previous');

    next.onclick = function(){
        nextSlide();
    };
    previous.onclick = function(){
        previousSlide();
    };
    
    document.getElementById('videoplay').addEventListener('ended', smoothly, false);
    function smoothly(e) {
        document.getElementById('notebook2a_1').checked = false;
        document.getElementById('notebook2a_2').checked = true;
        document.getElementById('notebook2a_2').checked = "checked";
    }
    </script>
        <style>

            .Window {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
                z-index: 99999;
                transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                display: none;
                pointer-events: none;
            }

            .Window:target {
                display: block;
                pointer-events: auto;
            }
            #centerlayer{
                margin-left:30%;
                margin-top:1%;
                width:600px;
                height:800px;
                background: url("thumbs/background.png") no-repeat;
                padding:10px;
            }
            .header{
                width:600px;
                height: 100px;
                position: relative;
                top:-10px;
                left:-10px;
            }
            #slides{
                position:relative;
                left:-20px;
                padding: 0;
                margin-top:-40px;
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            .slide{
                position: absolute;
                left:0;
                top:0;
                width:100%;
                height: 100%;
                opacity: 0;
                z-index: 1;
                -webkit-transition:opacity 1s;
                transition: opacity 1s;
            }
            .showing{
                opacity: 1;
                z-index: 2;
            }
            .slide{
                padding:40px;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                background-size: cover;
            }
            .container{
                position: relative;
            }
            .controls{
                z-index: 3;
                position: relative;
                float:left;
                top:305px;
                left:10px;
                transition-duration: 0.4;
                overflow: hidden;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .thumbs{
                position: relative;
                margin-left:105px;
                width:383px;
                height:74px;
                top:550px;
                cursor:pointer;
            }
            .thumbs img {
                margin-left:18px;
            }
            .mainImage{
                margin-top: -50px;
            }
            ul{
                list-style: none;
                padding: 0;
            }
            .thumbs li{
                display: inline-block;
                width:55px;
                margin-top:45px;
                margin-left:35px;
                cursor: pointer;
            }
            .active{
                border-radius: 100px;
                background-color: white;
            }
            .button1{
                position: absolute;
                float: right;
            }
            .button2{
                float:right;
                margin-right: 60px;
                margin-top:5px;
            }
            a{
                position: relative;
                color: white;
                text-decoration: none;
                float: left;
                font-size: large;
                font-family: "Bodoni MT Black";
            }
            .notebook2 {
                width: 640px;
                height: 450px;
                position: relative;
            }

            .notebook2 > input {
                display: none;
            }

            .notebook2 > div {
                position: absolute;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                top: 30px;
                left: 0px;
                bottom: 0px;
                right: 0px;
                border-radius: 10px;
                padding-top: 50px;
                z-index: 0;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0s, z-index 0s 0.5s;
            }

            .notebook2 > div > *:first-child {
                display: block;
                position: absolute;
                top: -30px;
                width: 150px;
                height: 30px;
                font-family: Arial;
                font-size: 13px;
                color: #fff;
                line-height: 28px;
                cursor: pointer;
                text-align: center;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
            }

            .notebook2 > div > *:not(:first-child) {
                opacity: 0;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0s;
            }

            .notebook2 > div:nth-of-type(1) > *:first-child { left: 20px; }
            .notebook2 > div:nth-of-type(2) > *:first-child { left: 170px; }

            .notebook2 > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(1),
            .notebook2 > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) {
                z-index: 10;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s, z-index 0s 0.5s;
            }

            .notebook2 > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(1) > *:first-child,
            .notebook2 > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) > *:first-child {
                color: #333;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
            }

            .notebook2 > input:nth-of-type(1):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(1) > *:not(:first-child),
            .notebook2 > input:nth-of-type(2):checked ~ div:nth-of-type(2) > *:not(:first-child)
            {
                opacity: 1;
                transition: all 0.5s ease 0.5s;
            }
            #video{
                width:580px;
            }
            .videocontent{
                width:580px;
                height: 380px;
                margin-top: 45px;
            }
        </style>
```

Я убрал `onended="smoothly()"` из тега видео, и в конце `javascript` добавил обработчик для `ended`;

Comment: @Влад добавте ваш `css` код в вопрос и сделайте его рабочим, и тогда ответ будет полноценным, я не знаю как выглядит ваши табы/

Comment: @Влад код нужен был что бы понять как скрываются и отображаются ваши табы. это объясните мне и код поправлю в ответе

Comment: @Влад а я поправил ответ, посмотрите так должно работать.

Comment: @Ramzik Galstyan нет , не вышло .. я добавил в функцию smoothly то что вы написали но не выходит

Comment: @Влад нет в эту функцию надо просто написать `nextSlyde()`

Comment: написал . не вышло

Comment: Если написать ответ первый , а потом в функцию smootly next slide() то при окончаннии видео таб Video вообще исчезает

Comment: @Влад Вот вам рабочий вариант.

Comment: Сработало огромное Спасибо